# What is the probability of getting an even number from a Poisson random draw?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Below is a graph showing the probability of drawing an odd number (y-axis) from a Poisson distribution with a given expected value (x-axis)

```
x = seq(0,1e4,1)         // range of values to explore 
lambdas = seq(0,4,0.01)  // expected value of the Poison distribution

FracOdd = numeric(n+1)       // response variable
for (i in 1:length(lambdas)) 
{
   FracOdd[i] = sum(dpois(x,lambdas[i])[seq(2,length(x),2)])  // calculate probability of drawing an odd number
}

plot(y=FracOdd,x=lambdas, type="l", lwd=3, xlab="Expected value", ylab="Probability of drawing an odd number")   // plot the data
```

[image]

It seems that the probability of drawing an odd number from a Poisson distribution with non-infinite mean is always lower than the probability of drawing an even number.

- What is the intuition for why the probability of drawing an odd number from a Poisson distribution always below 0.5?
- Is the function I drew numerically, easy to derive analytically?

Comment: Have you tried computing the probability analytically? I guess you will easily get $\frac{1}{2}(1-e^{-2\lambda})$ for odd draws of Poisson distribution of rate $\lambda$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\expo{-\lambda}\lambda^{2n} \over \pars{2n}!}} =
\expo{-\lambda}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\lambda^{n} \over n!}\,{1 + \pars{-1}^{n} \over 2}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\,\expo{-\lambda}\
\underbrace{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\lambda^{n} \over n!}}_{\ds{\expo{\lambda}}}\ +\
{1 \over 2}\,\expo{-\lambda}\
\underbrace{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-\lambda}^{n} \over n!}}_{\expo{-\lambda}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{1 + \expo{-2\lambda}\over 2} \\ &
\end{align}

Comment: Oh ok, I get the derivation. Thanks +1. Is there a nice intuition behind this result?

Comment: @Remi.b Thanks. You're welcome.

Comment: Can someone help me understand how do we get 2 out from (2n)! ?
and why we move to $\lambda^n$ loosing - along the way.

Comment: @Rotkiv I just added some details. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. Coming back to studying years after my calculus course, really appreciate you adding more details.

Comment: @Rotkiv Thanks.

Comment: Can you let me know how to get the first equal sign?

Comment: @Jackie Because it only counts those even numbers, for odd, the last term $\frac{1+(-1)^n}{2}=0$

Answer (score 9):

Yeah, it's reasonably well known.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(\text{Even}) ~&=~ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{\lambda^{2k} e^{-\lambda}}{(2k)!}\\[1ex] ~&=~ e^{-\lambda}\cosh(\lambda)\\[1ex] ~&=~ e^{-\lambda}\tfrac 12(e^{\lambda}+e^{-\lambda})\\[1ex]~&=~ \tfrac12(1+e^{-2\lambda})
\\[2ex]\mathsf P(\text{Odd}) ~&=~ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{\lambda^{2k+1} e^{-\lambda}}{(2k+1)!} \\[1ex]~&=~ e^{-\lambda}\sinh(\lambda)\\[1ex] ~&=~ e^{-\lambda}\tfrac 12(e^{\lambda}-e^{-\lambda})\\[1ex]~&=~ \tfrac12(1-e^{-2\lambda})\\[2ex]e^{-\lambda}(\cosh\lambda-\sinh\lambda)~&=~e^{-2\lambda}\end{align}$$