# Expected value of the number of experiments required to obtain the first success?

Tags: probability, expected-value, poisson-distribution

Two independent observations $X_1$ and $X_2$
are generated from the Poisson distribution with mean 1. The experiment is said to be successful if $X_1 + X_2$ is odd. What is the expected value of the number of experiments required to obtain the first success?
*Help to solve this problem.*

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you, say, compute the probability that $X_1$ is even?

Comment: May it be of help that the sum is Poisson with mean $2$?

Comment: Probability of even/odd results from a $\mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda)$ may be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2007238/what-is-the-probability-of-getting-an-even-number-from-a-poisson-random-draw.

Comment: i can find distribution of $X1+X2$ but for odd I don't know how to find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually solve it with an MC approach. The starting state, $\emptyset$ and the abosrbent state is $S_{odd/even, even/odd}$. This is because the only way to get an odd sum is for $X_1$ to be even and $X_2$ odd or vice versa. The probability of this event is 
$$
p_{\emptyset, 1} = P(X_1 = 2k+1)\times P(X_2=2k)\times 2 =2 e^{-2} \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z} }\frac{1}{(2k+1)!} \times \sum_{k\in  \mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{(2k!)}
$$
Now, to get the mean time until the state you need to compute
$$
m_{\emptyset ,1 } = 1+ p_{\emptyset, 1} \times 0 + (1-p_{\emptyset, 1})\times m_{\emptyset ,1 }
$$

Can you handle from here?